# Comparar Dataframes e mostrar as informações diferentes entre eles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho 2 dataframes, o **df_a** e **df_b**.

Como faço para compará-los e mostrar a informação que não está contida no dataframe **df_a**?

Tentei efetuar o método drop duplicates, no entanto, a saida apresenta os dados distintos entre as duas dataframes.

Abaixo o exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,5]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)

df_c = df_a.append(df_b)

df_d = df_c.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df_d
```

A saída fica dessa forma:

```
0
2   3
2   5
```

A minha necessidade é mostrar o resultado da linha que contem o valor 5 que é o valor do df_b diferente do df_a.

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa selecionar os valores diferentes entre as colunas na mesma posição do index, pode ser feito usando (1) `.loc` e (2) pegando os valores '*não iguais*' com o comando `.ne`

```
df_b.loc[df_b[0].ne(df_a[0])]
#saida
    0
2   5
```

Caso você queira selecionar os elementos em `df_b` que não se encontram em nenhuma posição em `df_a`, pode usar o comando `.isin` e negar a seleção, dessa forma.

```
df_b.loc[~df_b[0].isin(df_a[0])]
#saida
    0
2   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, se você duplicar a primeira df conforme código abaixo:

```
df_c = df_a.append(df_a)
```

O DataFrame 'df_c' será o df_a duplicado. Caso use o 'drop_duplicates', retornará apenas o cabeçalho da dataframe.

Para obter apenas as informações únicas do df_b, basta então fazer um append do df_b no df_c

```
df_d = df_c.append(df_b)
```

Assim, quando fizer o 'drop_duplicates'no df_d, será retirado tudo o que é similar entre o df_a e o df_b e todo o df_a, ficando somente as informações únicas df_b.

```
df_e = df_d.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

O resultado de df_e será:

```
    0
2   5
```

Assim, terá a informação que deseja.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente